# Unable to connect and load data from Oracle, using Ignite V2.0

Tags: java, ignite, in-memory-database

I am trying to configure and read data from existing Oracle tables
However, I get error message while calling `cache.loadCache();` this line.

It shows error message as 
Message as

```
session:javax.cache.integration.CacheWriterException: Failed to start store
session [tx=null]Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found
for jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.218:1521:xe at
org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getJdbcConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:190)  at
org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getXAConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:351)    at
org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getPooledConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:383)    at
org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnectionNow(JdbcConnectionPool.java:226)
at
org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnection(JdbcConnectionPool.java:198)
at




CacheConfiguration<String, TempClass> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<String, TempClass>();
            cacheCfg.setName("Test_CacheConfig");
            IgniteConfiguration igniteConfig = new IgniteConfiguration();
            Factory<TempClassCacheStore> factory = FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(TempClassCacheStore.class);

            cacheCfg.setReadThrough(true);
            cacheCfg.setWriteThrough(true);
            cacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(String.class, TempClass.class);
            cacheCfg.setCacheStoreFactory(factory);
            cacheCfg.setCacheStoreSessionListenerFactories(new Factory<CacheStoreSessionListener>() {
                @Override
                public CacheStoreSessionListener create() {
                    CacheJdbcStoreSessionListener lsnr = new CacheJdbcStoreSessionListener();
                    lsnr.setDataSource(JdbcConnectionPool.create("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.218:1521:xe", "test", "test"));
                    return lsnr;
                }
            });
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteConfig);
            IgniteCache<String, TempClass> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
            cache.loadCache(null);
            SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT ID_, NAME_  FROM TEST_TABLE");

            QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sql);
```

I have configured `CacheStore` for `TempClass` also as shown in
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store#cachestore
Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

As you're trying to load data from oracle to Ignite, you need to have Oracle JDBC Driver in classpath. Just put the driver JAR into IGNITE_HOME/libs folder prior to starting the nodes and run loading again.

Comment: Thanks @Evgenii Its kind of confusing I am starting ignite server from java program itself and I think it has nothing to do with the ignite binaries I have stored on my local computer, I haven't even set my ignite home. 
So I am confused how does it access the ignite instance stored on my local computer ?  And yes I already have oracle jar in my project's class path.

Comment: I didn't understand you, where and how are you starting ignite server? Do you have library in server's classpath?

Comment: I have icluded ingine libraries in my maven configuration of my java project as shown here.  https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/getting-started#get-it-with-maven     And using above code i am starting ignite instance. I dont have any other node running or set up on my PC. i.e. I dont start server using /ignite.bat file.

Comment: The error clearly indicates that JDBC driver is not found. Please double check and make sure it's on classpath.

Comment: Solved, Yes JDBC jar was in classpath however after cleaning few times error changed. Actually, the POJO class I was referring had a different name than the database table name.
BTW thanks for your answer.